# How to solve nonlinear systems of equations in R when the equations contain summation?

Tags: r

[image: the equation I need to solve]

n and each x_i is known, unknowns are \lambda and \mu.

my code like this:

```
library(BB)
n=100
l=0
s=1
sample=rcauchy(n,l,s)
fun<-function(x){
  f<-numeric(length(x))
  sum1=0
  sum2=0
  for (i in 1:n){
    sum1=sum1+sample[i]/(x[2]^2+(sample[i]-x[1])^2)
    sum2=sum2+1/(x[2]^2+(sample[i]-x[1])^2)
  }
  f[1]<-sum1-x[1]*n/(2*x[2]^2)
  f[2]<-sum2-n/(2*x[2]^2)
  f
}
startx<-c(0,0)
result = dfsane(startx,fun,control=list(maxit=500,trace = FALSE))
theta=result$par
```

the error is "Failure in initial functional evaluation"

Comment: Perhaps because `fun(c(0, 0))` returns `[1]  NaN -Inf` ?

Comment: Can confirm that if you give non-zero starting values it converges fine.

Comment: Also, no need for the `for` loop, you can do the sums simply like so: `sum1 <- sum(sample/(x[2] ^ 2+ (sample - x[1]) ^ 2))` and `sum2 <- sum(1 / (x[2] ^ 2 + (sample - x[1]) ^ 2))`

Comment: @Axeman I ignore that  x[2] is in the denominator, it works with starting value c(1,1), thank you very much! And thanks for reminding me of the sum function.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working, you were 99% of the way there!